# Is there any method in reinforcement Learning to select multiple simultaneous actions?

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn

I'm working on a research project that involves the application of reinforcement learning to planning and decision-making problems. Typically, these problems involve picking (sampling) multiple actions within a state based on ranking [max_q to min_q]. The RL literature seems focused on policies that map from a set of states to a single individual action not multiple. Does anyone know of approaches that can not only map states to multiple simultaneous actions but also that can maintain relationships between these actions? 
[Here is the DQN action selection function source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKBPX.png)

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by multiple actions? Could you give an example of an environment where you require this?

Comment: @nsidn98 Please check that link for my learning model environment https://imgur.com/a/zE4DAXe